# Считывание нескольких строк до перехода на новую строку

Tags: c++, строки

На вход поступает строка - точнее, несколько слов, разделенных пробелами - после происходит переход на новую строку, - пользователь нажимает `Enter`, - но перед получением следующей строки программа должна обработать предыдущую и выдать результат. Причем важно, чтобы очередное слово в строке считывалось в переменную типа `std::string` для дальнейшей обработки, - необязательно записывать каждое слово в уникальную переменную, можно затирать предыдущее значение.

Необходимо, чтобы программа была зациклена, то есть завершалась только после `Ctrl+C` или ключевого слова `exit`.

Ниже представлен условный алгоритм.

```
while (s != "exit")
{
    std::cin >> s;

    // Обработка слова в строке

    if (s == "\r\n")
    {
        //Вывод результата
    }
}
```

Трудность возникла именно с модулем считывания и обработки.

Comment: Ну и?.. Я задам вопрос вместо вас: " как сделать, чтобы  цикл завершился вводом Ctrl+C ?". Так?..

Comment: Не совсем. Сперва нужно выявить переход на новую строку - это триггер, который сообщает программе о завершении ввода первого массива данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то такое вам нужно?

```
void doit()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        istringstream is(line);
        string s;
        while(is >> s)
        {
            if (s == "exit") return;

            // ....
        }
        // строка закончилась
    }
}
```